# Using the lattice package to create panel plots of intervals and means of "parts of data"

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a panel plot (using xyplot if possible) for a line graph whose x-axis is months of the year and y-axis is the average rainfall in a given month over the 6 years the data spans.

There should be two levels in this panel plot: odd and even months.

Creating this plot without splitting it into levels is quite straightforward (creating a for loop to compute a vector of  averages) but the approach is not useful if you want to split the plots into different levels.

Here is the code:

```
dfmt <- "%d/%m/%Y"
date <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2010", dfmt), as.Date("31/12/2015", dfmt), 
    "day")
month <- months(date)
rainfall <- runif(2191, 0, 150)
monthsOfYear <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
    "November", "December")

parity <- match(month, monthsOfYear) %% 2
# even parity = 0, odd parity = 1

z <- data.frame(rainfall, date, month, parity)
```

And tried to plot using:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(months ~ allMeans(rainfall) | parity, data = z, layout = c(2,1))
```

Comment: What did you try with `lattice` package?

Comment: To be honest I'm pretty clueless. I wrote a function, allMeans, that computed a vector of all the averages (by month) of rainfall. Then I (naively) tried something like:

`code
xyplot(months ~ allMeans(rainfall) | parity, data = z, layout = c(2,1)) `

But obviously this won't work because allMeans(rainfall) is not a column from the data frame z.